# Split Strings in 3 (trigram) in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
col1
AAP CO. LTD.
AAS dds dTdD.
```

I am trying to create a function that produces a pandas df column like `col2` where it splits `col1` every 3 (or n) characters:

```
col1           col2
AAP CO. LTD.   ['AAP','AP ','P C','CO.','O. '...]
AAS dds dTdD.  ['AAS','AS ','S d','dds','ds '...]
```

I have tried this code, but it just repeats the same list of strings for every row...

```
def trigram(self):
    for b in df.parent_org_name:
        a = ["".join(j) for j in zip(*[b[i:] for i in range(3)])]
    #     [b[i:i+3] for i in range(len(b)-1)]
    return a
    #     print(a)
    
df.apply(trigram, axis=1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i don't really python anymore, but wouldn't range need to be dynamic.  LIke loop from i = 0...(b.length - 3), then range start at i ... i + 3

Comment: In this line "for b in df.parent_org_name" you are looping over all the rows of dataframe, Instead take current value and play with it

Comment: I'd love to give everyone a checkmark. So grateful for this app and this community. Thank you all for your help! I spent far too long trying to figure this out. Checkmark goes to the first answer - which is what is now working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more logic depending upon what should happen if you provide an `N` that is larger than the length of your string (Currently I return the original string in a list).

string slice, incrementing the slice start and stop indices by 1, and make sure you stop once you reach the end of the string, else you risk returning substrings that are <N in length.

```
import numpy as np

def split_str(s, N):
    rmax = np.clip(len(s)-N, a_min=0, a_max=None)+1
    return [s[0+i:N+i] for i in range(0, rmax)]

df['col1'].apply(lambda x: split_str(x, 3))
#0    [AAP, AP , P C,  CO, CO., O. , . L,  LT, LTD, ...
#1    [AAS, AS , S d,  dd, dds, ds , s d,  dT, dTd, ...
#Name: col1, dtype: object

# To show actual values
df['col1'].apply(lambda x: split_str(x, 3))[0]
#['AAP', 'AP ', 'P C', ' CO', 'CO.', 'O. ', '. L', ' LT', 'LTD', 'TD.']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need :). In case one needs to run it with a parameter n different from 3, then they may just change the i+3 accordingly in the brackets

```
df["col2"] = df.apply(lambda x: [x[0][i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(x[0]))],axis=1) 
#The result looks as follows

   col1          col2
0  AAP CO. LTD.  [AAP, AP , P C,  CO, CO., O. , . L,  LT, LTD, ... 
1  AAS dds dTdD. [AAS, AS , S d,  dd, dds, ds , s d,  dT, dTd, ...
```

Comment: Just be careful, `range` should stop at `range(0, len(x[0])-3+1)`, else you get additional <3 length strings like `'D.'` and `'.'` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over all rows, change your function definition as below-

```
def trigram(self):
    b=self.col1
    a = ["".join(j) for j in zip(*[b[i:] for i in range(3)])]
#        a = ["".join(j) for j in zip(*[b[i:] for i in range(3)])]
    #     [b[i:i+3] for i in range(len(b)-1)]
    return a
```